# SagePay Test account Pre-authorisation processing

Tags: authorization, opayo

I am currently setting up SagePay on the SagePay Test account. I want to Pre-authorise a payment (Hold) and then Capture the payment a few days later.  It appears however that I only have the option to invoke payment immediately - does anyone know how to perform Authorise then Capture a payment.

Comment: Did you look at deferred payments? http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/16/36/transaction-types

Answer (score 1):

Deferred will work. Authorisation with the bank is obtained at the point of sale and you have 30 days to Release the payment for settlement. Only at the point of Release will the process of transferring funds from the card issuing bank to the merchant bank begin.

You can Release a payment by clicking on the transaction in My Sage Pay or by sending a command across to Sage Pay from your internal web portal:

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/21071/download-document/SHARED_Protocol_Guidelines_010814.pdf?token=Bbx-WrTNysT6-HtttVME4so0nYzd-Tt8rWqLrQ_wdaA